# Minify HTML code into one line

Tags: vb.net

My program is generating HTML code, which is placed afterwards into some string variable. This HTML code is ready to be placed in CSV file, so the entire code is surrounded by quotes, as well as all inner double quotes have additional quotes for escape. The result is the user can see it nicely formatted in output.

However, I have to convert this code to one line as assuming that my excel having trouble with this 'well formatted' HTML code as there are line-breaks. Therefore, I want before I place into CSV to make this HTML code into one line. Can you tell me how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace line breaks by nothing to get a single lined output:

```
Dim TestString As String
TestString = " <body>" & vbCrLf & " some html" & vbCrLf & " </body>"
Dim SingleLined As String
SingleLined = Replace(TestString, vbCrLf, "")
```

Comment: but about html code content itself will be not influence on it? What if html code itself contain it or am i wrong?

Comment: Unless your html uses `<pre>` blocks, the newlines in the content will be represented by `<br />`.